# Can you identify this LEGO minifig head please, black with grey lines and silver eyes?

Tags: part-identification

My son's favorite LEGO minifig head, came in a box of loose LEGO. I have searched hundreds of images and have not found a match.

[image: black minifig head with grey lines]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [the head of the 2011 Star Wars V-Wing pilot](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0809).

[image]

It came in [7915 Imperial V-wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7915-1).

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I doubt I'd have ever found that. May I ask how you determined so quickly? Does this site have points I can upvote you with?

Comment: @williamnimmo I found it fairly quickly by searching ["silver" under minifig heads on BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=silver&catLike=W&catString=238&sortBy=N&sortAsc=A&itemBrand=0&catType=P&v=1). You don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but you can accept this answer.